# хочу add_custom_command настроить сборку справки проекта

Tags: qt, cmake

```
set(STATISTIC_DOC_OUTPUT_DIR   ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc)
set(STATISTIC_DOC_SRC          ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/help)

add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT "${STATISTIC_DOC_OUTPUT_DIR}/doc.qch"
        COMMAND qhelpgenerator doc.qhp -o doc.qch
        WORKING_DIRECORY ${STATISTIC_DOC_SRC}
        COMMENT "generated docs"
)
```

не компилируется файл

```
doc.qch
```

в папке help лежат все картинки и *.html файлы
этой командой я хочу чтобы они собрались в бинарник, и затем переместились в /doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильное решение - добавить таргет, зависящий от создаваемого в команде файла:

```
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT "${STATISTIC_DOC_OUTPUT_DIR}/doc.qch"
        COMMAND qhelpgenerator doc.qhp -o doc.qch
        WORKING_DIRECORY ${STATISTIC_DOC_SRC}
        COMMENT "generated docs"
)

add_custom_target(docs ALL DEPENDS ${STATISTIC_DOC_OUTPUT_DIR}/doc.qch)
```

`add_custom_command` определяет правило, позволяющее произвести файл, указанный в `OUTPUT`. `add_custom_target` создает цель (как, например, в Makefile), которая зависит от файла, создаваемого командой. Поэтому `make docs` будет производить этот файл. `ALL` добавляет таргет `docs` в таргет `all`, поэтому документация будет собираться просто при `make`.

Answer (score 0):

я не знаю почему та штука не работала. НО вот так работает:

```
add_custom_command(
        TARGET ${APPNAME}
        PRE_BUILD
        COMMAND qhelpgenerator "${STATISTIC_DOC_SRC}/doc.qhp" -o "${STATISTIC_DOC_OUTPUT_DIR}/doc.qch"
        COMMAND qcollectiongenerator "${STATISTIC_DOC_SRC}/StatisticHelp.qhcp" -o "${STATISTIC_DOC_OUTPUT_DIR}/StatisticHelp.qhc"
        COMMENT "generated docs"
)
```